# Problem authentication Ubuntu

Tags: server, connection, error-handling, filezilla

I'm trying to upload some files on my server but I getting this error after the password had been changed.

**Someone could help me to figure out what's the problem?
I tried to close and reopen the filezilla, and uninstalled the filezilla and installed again.**

**Error**

```
Command:    USER painfree@thorpeinnovation.com
Response:   331 User painfree@thorpeinnovation.com OK. Password required
Command:    PASS ***********
Response:   530 Login authentication failed
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

Comment: The password you're using now is probably incorrect.

Comment: The password had been changed, and I using the new one. But After the password had been changed I got this problem. Seems that the ftp asks for the password everytime I try to transfer any file to the server. But couldn't find the password, and because of this the connection can't be completed successful.

Comment: Again, if it doesn't accept the password you're using now it's probably because it's wrong.

Comment: But I can connect to the server and see all the files (using this new password), I just can't upload nothing.

Comment: Well, that's new information. And it means that *probably* it wasn't only the password that changed but the permissions as well. You should contact the person who's managing the server. If it you then you should check permissions yourself, it's likely read-only now.

Comment: Or you need to delete that profile and create a new one in FileZilla.